# Htaccess redirecting wild subdomain to new host as parameter + hiding new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Basically I created `*.domain.com` A record for my vps.
Managed to redirect any `*.domain.com` to new directory where is `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/test.php?id=%1 [L]
```

With this, it redirects ie. `tits.domain.com` to `domain.com/test.php?id=tits`.
But my question is: What do i need to add to `.htaccess` file IN `domain.com` directory so the address will be hidden ? I want redirect to `domain.com/test.php?id=tits`, but i want url bar to show `tits.domain.com`.
Regards.

Comment: Redirecting to a different hostname will always force an external redirect. If you want to preserve the original hostname, you have to use mod_proxy ...e.g. `RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/test.php?id=%1 [P]` Check out: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Comment: However if i change `[L]` to `[P]` it stops to work and when i go to `tits.domain.com` it shows error 404 that the requested url was not found `tits.domain.com/index.html` ... Any ideas why?

Comment: Im not pro in `.htaccess` but i found one solution but couldnt get to work. Maybe you will know what they meant. They answered that he needs to make like i did in 1 host, and in htaccess file that is in the 2nd host he needs to do same but the opposite so the htaccess will be reversed and it wont go more then 1 time a loop...

Comment: If all these domains are mapped to this same server, is there a reason you're not just leaving the requested hostname? `RewriteRule .* test.php?id=%1 [L]` Rewrites require a decent understanding of how URLs are manipulated and what your exact requirements are.  There's not much margin for error. Also, there are other considerations in an environment which may affect pre or post execution, like other Rewrites, Redirects, Alias, DirectoryIndex...etc.

Comment: Helpful documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html   I   
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite   |   
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html